# Unable to publish "Docs web addon"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-apps

We currently have a published docs web add on that was originally published in 2016.  It looks like now add on's need to be attached to a GCP project.  When I try to publish a new version I receive the following error : "API Console project with the id specified in the manifest's api_console_project_id field, does not have Google Apps Marketplace SDK enabled."  See screenshot.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3lDE.png)

Also, when I go into the script under resources there is no "Cloud Platform Project" link, see screenshot.

[No menu option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEO4o.png)

Also, when I go under "Advanced Google Services" and click on  "Google API Console" I get the following error screen when trying to load up the GCP Project.

I'm trying to keep this current listing as I already have a large user base, I just need to somehow associate a new GCP project with an existing add-on.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.